# "drawing" char/string shapes by a variable diagonal length in haskell

Tags: string, haskell, char

I'm looking for a function (let's name it diamond) that "draws" a diamond-shaped "object" by defining only the length of it's diagonal (e.g.: as shown below, so the length of the diagonal in this case is 5 "*" but only 3 are visible):

```
Main> diamond 5

Output:
   *
  ***
 *****
  ***
   *
```

I have these functions:

```
stars x 
    | (x mod 2 == 1) = (firstHalf x) ++ [x] ++ reverse(firstHalf x)
    | otherwise = (firstHalf x) ++ reverse(firstHalf x)`

firstHalf x = take (x div 2) (iterate (2+) 1)

space x = map (div 2) (map ((x+1)-) (stars x))
```

Example output:

```
space 5 = [2,1,0,1,2]
stars 5 = [1,3,5,3,1]
```

This function might work but I don't know how to fix this error:

Type error in application:

- Expression     : replicate (stars x) ['*']
- Term           : stars x
- Type           : [Int]
- Does not match : Int

`diamond x = mapM_ putStrLn $ (replicate (space x) [' ']) ++ (replicate (star x) ['*'])`

And I guess even if this error was fixed it would still need a tweak that would join those two lists to get the desired result. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm new to haskell, I mostly work on an arithmetical basis, I'm not really familiar with these types of functions and so on. If you could tell me a basic idea how to write one line of those "stars" by some mathematical calculations + putting string on the output if you know what I mean.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the `homework` tag. We will still attempt to give some answers, but will adjust the way we answer to avoid doing things that might be against your school's code of conduct, to avoid getting you in trouble.

Comment: Don't worry it's not homework but thank you.

Comment: You are getting close, @baron.  Take a look at `mapM_` and `zip` -- they will allow you to iterate over your lists and do an action for each pair.

Comment: I'm trying but I still can't figure it out how could I put all these functions together to make it work. I updated my question above to see where I got so far. Thanks for your patience and help so far @luqui.

Comment: `zip (space 5) (stars 5) = [(2,1),(1,3),(0,5),(1,3),(2,1)]`.  Now make a function `line (nspaces, nstars) = ...`, which you can pass to `mapM_`.  (Note that it takes a tuple and not arguments in curried style -- this is because `zip` returns a list of tuples)

Comment: And thank *you* for working with me to solve the problem instead of just expecting an easy answer :-).

Comment: Than you @luqui very much! Your help is very appreciated! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can generate a number of stars with `replicate`:

```
ghci> replicate 5 '*'
"*****"
```

You can also do this with any other character, such as a space (`' '`).

You can print a line to the screen with `putStrLn`:

```
ghci> putStrLn (replicate 5 '*')
*****
```

Here is a program that generates the star above:

```
main = do
    putStrLn $ replicate 2 ' ' ++ replicate 1 '*'
    putStrLn $ replicate 1 ' ' ++ replicate 3 '*'
    putStrLn $ replicate 0 ' ' ++ replicate 5 '*'
    putStrLn $ replicate 1 ' ' ++ replicate 3 '*'
    putStrLn $ replicate 2 ' ' ++ replicate 1 '*'
```

You can define functions with `=`:

```
hello x = putStrLn $ "Hello " ++ x
main = do
    hello "Bob"  -- prints "Hello Bob"
```

(If you do this from the ghci prompt, you have to say `let` first: eg. `let hello x = putStrLn $ "Hello " ++ x`)

I don't know why I spent so much time on this question, but I felt like it.  Typically we want questions to provide some evidence that you have spent some time trying to solve the problem before asking for help. Merry Christmas...

I have given you all the pieces.  Now you have to put them together.

Comment: Very much appreciated. Thank you.
The last thing I'm looking for is that is there a way to "draw" this with the help of thses functions:
 
stars x | (x `mod` 2 == 1) = (firstHalf x) ++ [x] ++ reverse(firstHalf x)
        | otherwise = (firstHalf x) ++ reverse(firstHalf x)

firstHalf x = take (x `div` 2) (iterate (2+) 1)

space x = map (`div` 2) (map ((x+1)-) (stars x))

then:
space 5 = [2,1,0,1,2]
stars 5 = [1,3,5,3,1]

Is there a way to print the shape above from these two lists ? My basic idea:

putStrLn $ replicate [2,1,0,1,2] ' ' ++ replicate 1 '*' [1,3,5,3,1] --until the list is empty